# Not getting expected result from .toHaveBeenCalledTimes() in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Anyhow, trying to test if a function has been called after its fired. The `fireEvent` is working as I get a `console.log` from that function. But the `.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` returns 0. What have i missed?

If I have the `handleLoginSubmit` function in the parent and pass it as a prop down to the child and in the test everything passes. But if it's in the same component it fails. Using typescript if that has any meaning.

This is tested

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

type Event = React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;

interface Login {
  handleLoginSubmit?: (event: Event) => React.ReactNode;
}

const Login: FC<Login> = () => {
  const handleLoginSubmit = (_event: Event) => {
    console.log('Firing' ); // This is logged
  };

  return (
    <form data-testid='form' onSubmit={(event) => handleLoginSubmit(event)}>
      <input data-testid='email'/>
      <input data-testid='password'/>
      <button data-testid='login-button'>login</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

My test for submiting

```
  it('should handle ClickEvents', () => {

    const handleLoginSubmit = jest.fn();

    const { getByTestId } = render(<Login/>);

    expect(getByTestId('login-button')).toBeTruthy();

    fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('form'));

    expect(handleLoginSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  });
```

Error message

```
 ● Login page › should handle ClickEvents

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      32 |     fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('form'));
      33 | 
    > 34 |     expect(handleLoginSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                               ^
      35 | 
      36 |   });
      37 | });

      at Object.it (__tests__/components/Login.test.tsx:34:31)
```

Comment: The issue here is that you are assigning `handleLoginSubmit` to a variable but the one inside <Login /> is just different although sharing the same name (it is scoped on the component).

If you want it to work, pass `handleLoginSubmit` to the component as an `onSubmit` prop and then mock the prop like

`render(<Login onSubmit={handleLoginSubmit} />)`

and it will be called

Comment: How do you mean passing `onSubmit` as an prop? Do you mean pass it from the parent down to the `Login` component? I do not want to do that i think as i want the function call in that component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't assert if the `handleLoginSubmit` function is to be called directly. Since it's defined in the private scope of `Login` SFC. You can't mock or spy on this function because you can't access it. So, you need to test it indirectly. Since you are using `console.log` in this function, we can spy `console.log`. If it's been called, that means the `handleLoginSubmit` function has been called.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { FC } from "react";

type Event = React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;

interface Login {
  handleLoginSubmit?: (event: Event) => React.ReactNode;
}

const Login: FC<Login> = () => {
  const handleLoginSubmit = (_event: Event) => {
    console.log("Firing");
  };

  return (
    <form data-testid="form" onSubmit={event => handleLoginSubmit(event)}>
      <input data-testid="email" />
      <input data-testid="password" />
      <button data-testid="login-button">login</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Login from "./";
import React from "react";

it("should handle ClickEvents", () => {
  const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "log");
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Login />);
  expect(getByTestId("login-button")).toBeTruthy();
  fireEvent.submit(getByTestId("form"));
  expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59162138/index.spec.tsx
  ✓ should handle ClickEvents (42ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    Firing

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.987s, estimated 9s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59162138

Comment: Ah okey, so when testing for a console.log (or other console outouts) we need to specify that in a spy? So when testing for lets say state, we need a spy thats takes react, and state or similar as arguments? Thanks btw!

Comment: Test the state of the component, don't test the implementation details of functions defined in the SFC. Which means the functions(hooks, event handlers, etc..) will change the state of the component. You should assert the state of the component.

Comment: Okey, so if I want to test a forms input changeevent i should not test the function that is handle the state/event and rather the output in the DOM/what outputs in the actual input fields?

Comment: @GameAtrix Yes. Besides, you can't access the change event handler if it's defined in the private scope within your SFC. So, you can't add a spy and mock it.   You need test the updated state/prop of your component (the outputs in the actual input fields)